# Photoshop Actions are inconsistent between devices

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm having this issue where I have a Photoshop Action work on one machine, but when I port it to another machine, it errors out halfway through because one of the layers are empty, or some other issue. I've reset preferences on both Photoshop instances. I've exported all brushes, patterns and actions from one machine, and transferred them to another machine. Before adding them to the other machine I removed all actions, brushes, and patterns. And yet it still errors. I noticed that the Artistic Cutout effect would produce different results sometimes.

I don't know. I feel like I'm losing my mind. Does anyone have any ideas? I even disabled GPU support on both machines and it still worked on my machine but not the other.

Comment: Kind of impossible to answer without specific action steps and machines to test.